# smarctl - SSD dying due to age? other hardware fault causing SSD failure?

Tags: ssd, smartctl

Trying to interpret the **smartctl** output from an SSD to understand if this SSD errors are a result of age or possibly other hardware errors causing the disk to fail?

Those of you who understand smartctl outputs, what do you reckon? Thanks in advance!

a. I see the `Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk` value is `3590` Does that mean the SSD controller will internally keep allocating these blocks to use and it has lots of headroom still left?

b. I read using `badblocks` on SSDs is not a good idea given that SSD controllers internally reallocate where data is stored, so what is the most optimum thing to do .. reformat this to `ext4`? `btrfs`?

This is a `Crucial MX300 750GB` drive purchased in 2016. It's not seen very heavy usage. Power on Hours is < 1000, working out TiBs from Total_LBAs_Written is 4.5 (no ?) but is showing 11 bad sectors.

The system had experienced a few power failures when I had an issue in the electrical circuit that caused the RCD to go off, before I got hold of an UPS.

Needless to say, I won't be keeping any valuable data on this drive. Planning to use this drive for testing purposes only, but trying to understand what is happening with the drive.

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   100   100   000    -    33
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt -O--CK   100   100   010    -    11
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    886
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    374
171 Program_Fail_Count      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   -O--CK   099   099   000    -    15
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    134
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift -O--CK   100   100   000    -    26
184 Error_Correction_Count  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    857
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   075   047   000    -    25 (Min/Max 10/53)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    11
197 Current_Pending_ECC_Cnt -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   100   100   000    -    46
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain ----CK   099   099   001    -    1
206 Write_Error_Rate        -OSR--   100   100   000    -    0
246 Total_LBAs_Written      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    9221679267
247 Host_Program_Page_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    288188932
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    140037332
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk PO--CK   000   000   000    -    3590
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  -O--CK   100   100   000    -    60
```

The [full smartctl output can be found here](https://pastebin.com/vDqtUdmh): https://pastebin.com/vDqtUdmh

Comment: My two cents: In the pastebin I read "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED", which tells me that your drive is not dying, but has passed the overall health test. - There are 2 pre-failure warnings, P flag for Raw_Read_Error_Rate and Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk, So you should watch the raw values listed for those attributes, and if they change signifcantly, you may come near a serious failure.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no "quick-and-easy", "one-size-fits-all" answers to your questions. For one thing, SMART data is very dependent upon the manufacturer. You may wish to do some research on this... for example: [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=can+smartctl+diagnose+SSD&t=newext&atb=v369-1&ia=web), [result 1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/a7-narayanan.pdf?ref=linuxhandbook.com), [result 2](https://linuxhandbook.com/check-ssd-health/).